# Cannot toggleClass properly with active and focus

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a search bar that will effectively push things out of the way when active. Currently the code as it is will push everything, but when it is out of focus, only the search_bar will return to its previous state. When I add blur to the mix, everything toggles as it should but I can no longer type into the search_bar. Why can't I get these things to work properly?
Here is a full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/bbrP9/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".search_bar").bind('focus active', function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('search_bar_focus');
      $('.search_button').toggleClass('search_button_focus');
      $('.logo').toggleClass('logo_focus');
  });
```

**Edit:** It is worth noting that when I add blur into it, the whole thing may randomly start working but when I reload the page it won't and then it will and back and forth. There is no consistency to it.

Comment: There is no `active` event, there's an `onactivate`event for old IE only, but I think you just want blur and focus, and to show us the problem, you should set up a fiddle, as the classes are clearly toggled ?

Comment: Working on the fiddle now, but for me active detects when I am using something like the search bar. It's kinda like focus but it puts the cursor in the search bar so I can start typing, where focus just expands and if I try to click on the search bar I lose it.

Comment: You realise you set `font-size: 0px;` on the input box? Setting that to a actual number makes it work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/7vCvh/1/

Comment: hm yeah imagine that. I did that so the text wouldn't be visible otherwise it's an annoying speck on the page until you activate it.

Comment: Seems to work for me, but try this and see if it's more consistent -> http://jsfiddle.net/bbrP9/1/

Comment: negative indent the text then: http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/bbrP9/2/ The only way it doesn't work for me is when the font-size is 0

Comment: @adeneo That's neat, didn't know you could pass in a list of events and handlers like that.

Comment: @jammykam - Yup, most jQuery methods will accept a map of events as well as the usual strings etc.

Comment: cool but I think I'm going to go with jammykam's solution, unless there is some additional benefit to adeneo's

Comment: I just realized I updated @adeneo's fiddle for my example... Only difference I can see is how the text appears (scale vs slide) but adeneo may be able to comment of performance better than I can. I'd add an answer anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to lie around the 0px setting of the search bar input field. Setting the `font-size` to the correct value and negative `text-indent` to hide the text solves the issue.

**CSS**

```
.search_bar {
    /* everything else remains the same */
    font-size: 12px;
    text-indent: -999px;
}
.search_bar:focus, .search_bar:active {
    /* everything else remains the same, remove font-size*/
    text-indent: 0px;
}
```

The rest of the code remains unchanged.

You also have the alternative of using Adeneo's excellent answer linked in the comments.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/7vCvh/3/)